# Android auto sync and power saving mode

Tags: android, wifi, image-uploading, samsung-mobile, google-photos

I am using Google photos to back up my all the photos. So in my Samsung galaxy J7 2016 phone, I have turned on auto sync and it is set to use only in wifi. So whenever I connected to a wifi network it automatically uploads all photos to google photos. This is the process. I know you all know that.

My question is that when the power saving mode on, does sync disabled for temporary or I have to on that again in manual after disabling power saving mode or it is automatically on after disabling the power saving?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that when the power saving mode on, does sync disabled
>   for temporary?

Yes.
Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby):

> In Doze mode, the system attempts to **conserve battery by restricting
>   apps' access to network and CPU-intensive services**. It also prevents
>   apps from accessing the network and defers their jobs, **syncs**, and
>   standard alarms.

**For the question:**

> or I have to on that again in manual after disabling power saving mode
>   or it is automatically on after disabling the power saving?

You don't have to do anything.

> As soon as the user wakes the device by moving it, turning on the screen, or connecting a charger, the system exits Doze and all apps return to normal activity.

Even when in doze mode, system has some maintenance windows, during which the pending syncs will be executed.